# Why am I getting Gwibber notifications without Gwibber installed?

Tags: gwibber, hotot

I removed Gwibber as soon as I installed Ubuntu. I used Gwibber on another Ubuntu computer, and didn't like it.

I didn't mind the notifications from Gwibber when I got new @replies, but I just installed Hotot, and like it a lot. But, I am getting notifications from Hotot and Gwibber, even though I dont have Gwibber installed, and havent for months.  How can I fix/get rid of this?

Comment: Wait, you are **not** getting notifications from Hotot and Gwibber? Or you are?

Comment: When I go to the software center, it shows that Gwibber is _not_ installed. But, when someone mentions me on Twitter, gwibber _and_ hotot _are_ giving me notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `sudo apt-get autoremove gwibber`  to remove the package.

Also remove the data from .config folder.

`rm ~/.config/gwibber`

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. Though, the `rm ~/.config/gwibber` command didn't work. But `sudo apt-get autoremove gwibber` did work... this is what I got from Terminal: `Package gwibber is not installed, so not removed
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gnome-web-photo libaccess-bridge-java libaccess-bridge-java-jni
  libbabl-0.0-0 libgegl-0.0-0 libgsl0ldbl libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a libindicate-qt1
  python-uniconvertor rhythmbox-data wine-gecko1.4 wine-gecko1.6`